# Displaying text with VBScript when running from command prompt issue

Tags: vbscript, scripting, message, command-prompt, wsh

I have a script that pings a list of computers and tells me if I can be reached. For each computer I would like it to display whether or not it was reached on the command prompt, not as a pop-up message. I did Wscript.Echo, but it does a pop-up for each computer so it's really annoying to have to click OK over a 100 times.

How can I make it display on the command prompt itself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you call it like this it will print to the console:

```
cscript myscript.vbs
```